# Submodular welfare maximization: what is the best known approximation ratio of a deterministic algorithm?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, optimization, submodularity

In the *submodular welfare maximization problem*, there is a set $M$ of items that should be partitioned among $n$ agents. Each agent $i$ has a value function $v_i: 2^M\to \mathbb{R}_+$. All value functions are monotonically-increasing and submodular. The goal is to find a partition $M = X_1\cup \cdots \cup X_n$, such that the sum of agents' values $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i(X_i)$ is maximized.

It is known that a greedy algorithm attains a $1/2$-approximation to this problem.
[Vondrak (2008)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1374376.1374389) presented a randomized algorithm that attains a $(1-1/e)$ approximation (in expectation), in the value oracle model; this algorithm has been generalized by [Calinescu, Chekuri, Pal and Vondrak (2011)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/080733991), but their algorithm is randomized too.

[Feige and Vondrak (2010)](http://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v006a011/v006a011.pdf) present an algorithm that attains an approximation slightly better than $(1-1/e)$ in the demand-oracle model, but their algorithm, too, uses randomized rounding.

What is the best known approximation ratio for this problem, using a deterministic polynomial-time algorithm?